# How to check if an item in an object's string list also exists in other string lists in different objects with the same identifier?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I have a list

```
var resource = new List<Resource>();
```

the Resource looks like this

```
public class Resource
{
    public int RepatedId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Different resource objects can have the same RepeatedId

and my main goal is to find pairs of resource objects where an element from Data list exists in another resource object under the same RepeatedId.

I grouped resources by RepatedId

```
var grouped = resource.GroupBy(x => x.RepatedId , x => x.Data);
```

but I don't have any idea how can I take the first element from Data in the first resource and iterate through others to find the same element in different objects.

Example data:

```
var resource = new List<Resource>
{
    new Resource
    {
        RepatedId = 1,
        Name = "whatever",
        Data = new List<string>
        {
            "example1",
            "example11",
            "example111"
        }
    },
    new Resource
    {
        RepatedId = 2,
        Name = "whatever",
        Data = new List<string>
        {
            "example2",
            "example11",
            "example222"
        }
    },
    new Resource
    {
        RepatedId = 1,
        Name = "whatever",
        Data = new List<string>
        {
            "example2",
            "example11",
            "example222"
        }
    },
    new Resource
    {
        RepatedId = 1,
        Name = "whatever",
        Data = new List<string>
        {
            "example3",
            "example22",
            "example11"
        }
    },
};
```

I need pairs of all combinations.
So in the first element, I have "example11" which is also in the third and fourth(also in the second, but it doesn't have the same RepeatedId),
should be like this

- the first resource object and the third
- first and fourth
- third and fourth

The question is:

How can I iterate through the collection to find combination pairs and return them(returning a pair of resource objects)?

Comment: sounds like you need a  loop with registry like list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine the group dropping the last member with the same group skipping the first member, and exclude the pairings where the members are the same, then you can filter for the pairs where there is an element in the first member's `Data` that is in the second member's `Data`:

```
var ans = resource
            .GroupBy(r => r.RepatedId)
            .SelectMany(rg => rg.Take(rg.Count()-1)
                                .SelectMany((r1,n) => rg.Skip(n+1).Select(r2 => new { r1, r2 })))
            .Where(rp => rp.r1.Data.Any(d1 => rp.r2.Data.Contains(d1)))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Everything seems to be working fine. I have to practice my linq skills more.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this query, but why are we dropping the last grouping member?

Comment: @Krystian Do you mean the `Take(rg.Count()-1)`? Because we are matching the group members up in pairs, an the last member has nothing it can match. However, the `Skip(1)` is not helping much and could be removed.

Comment: @Krystian Actually, the `Skip(1)` was an error - with longer groups, it allows for backwards matches (e.g. the answer has 3,4 and 4,3). I have fixed the code to skip past the already matched resources in the second list.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. Thanks a lot! :)